# ASMX consume as WCF service and additional argumnet of method is HEADER, what should pass for HEADER

Tags: wcf, web-services, asmx, webservice-client

I had consumed ASMX service in vs 2008. and at that time, calling method is look as below:

```
      PostTravelData(TravelTransaction)
      //NOTE: property - "TOKENID" was set before calling to this method.
```

Now, I have used same ASMX service into VS2012 and added as service reference so, it consumed as WCF service.

NOw, in method signature has one additional argumnet called - "HEADER". so signature looks as below:

```
      PostTravelData(Header,TravelTransaction OUT TravelTransactionResponse)
```

**Please suggest me what should i pass as Header. i am not clear what should i have to pass as HEADER argument.
I tried by passing direclty TOKENID value as header but still not work.
Do i have to create object of type "RequestHeader" and keep argumnet as "TokenID" and then pass to the argumnet of that method ?**

Below is the SOAP wsdl:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soap:Header>
     <RequestHeader xmlns="http://www.example.com/Soa/Foundation/">
       <Headers>
        <anyType />
      <anyType />
    </Headers>
    </RequestHeader>
  </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
  <TravelTransaction xmlns="http://www.example.com/Soa/Foundation/">
    <TravelTransactionRequest xmlns="http://www.example.com/Soa/Foundation/MessageDefinition.xsd">
      <TravelData>
        <TravelMsg>           
        <IsExcused>boolean</IsExcused>
          <ScheduledMeetingId>int</ScheduledMeetingId>
         <Comment>string</Comment>
         <PostAttForScheduledPeriods>boolean</PostAttForScheduledPeriods>
       </TravelMsg>
        <TravelMsg>
        <IsExcused>boolean</IsExcused>
        <ScheduledMeetingId>int</ScheduledMeetingId>
        <Comment>string</Comment>
        <PostAttForScheduledPeriods>boolean</PostAttForScheduledPeriods>
            </TravelMsg>
           </TravelData>
         </TravelTransactionRequest>
       </TravelTransaction>
      </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: That is not a WSDL. That's just the message.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the namespace of the service you added there should be an object for the header.

You need to create this object, populate any properties as required and pass this as the parameter.